# Match and replace operation in data frame in R

Tags: r, replace, pattern-matching, match, vlookup

Let's say my dataset is like the following:

```
John   NA    kaira   
carry  John  NA
maya   Sam   maya
leo    paty  leo
tinker NA    tinker
fabo   leo   maya
```

I have another dataset:

```
John   1
carry  2
maya   3
leo    4
tinker 5
fabo   6
sam    7
paty   8 
kaira  9
```

I want to match the values of the above table (df2) with first table (df1) so my final table (df) looks like the following:

```
1   NA   9   
2   1    NA
3   7    3
4   8    4
5   NA   5
6   4    3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could also do

```
df1[] <- match(unlist(df1), df2$V1)
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1 NA  9
# 2  2  1 NA
# 3  3 NA  3
# 4  4  8  4
# 5  5 NA  5
# 6  6  4  3
```

If the numbers in `df2` are not always in order, abit adjust code would be

```
df1[] <- df2[match(unlist(df1), df2$V1), 2]
```

Comment: Clever, minimalist and efficient. +1

Comment: Neat and base R. +1 as well!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `match` to accomplish the lookup:

```
apply(df1, 2, function(x) df2[,2][match(x, df2[,1])])
     V1 V2 V3
[1,]  1 NA  9
[2,]  2  1 NA
[3,]  3 NA  3
[4,]  4  8  4
[5,]  5 NA  5
[6,]  6  4  3
```

You'll notice I have an extra `NA` value in the second column because "Sam" from the first data frame does not match "sam" from the second data frame due to case sensitivity. If you don't care about case sensitivity you might try:

```
apply(df1, 2, function(x) df2[,2][match(tolower(x), tolower(df2[,1]))])
#      V1 V2 V3
# [1,]  1 NA  9
# [2,]  2  1 NA
# [3,]  3  7  3
# [4,]  4  8  4
# [5,]  5 NA  5
# [6,]  6  4  3
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% mutate_each(funs(df2[,2][match(., df2[,1])]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `mapvalues` from `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
mapvalues(tolower(as.matrix(df)), tolower(df1$V1), df1$V2)

#     V1  V2  V3 
#[1,] "1" NA  "9"
#[2,] "2" "1" NA 
#[3,] "3" "7" "3"
#[4,] "4" "8" "4"
#[5,] "5" NA  "5"
#[6,] "6" "4" "3"
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(V1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L), .Label = c("carry", 
"fabo", "John", "leo", "maya", "tinker"), class = "factor"), 
V2 = structure(c(NA, 1L, 4L, 3L, NA, 2L), .Label = c("John", 
"leo", "paty", "Sam"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(1L, 
NA, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("kaira", "leo", "maya", "tinker"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df1 = structure(list(V1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 
4L), .Label = c("carry", "fabo", "John", "kaira", "leo", "maya", 
"paty", "sam", "tinker"), class = "factor"), V2 = 1:9), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without it converting the output to strings? I'd suppose you can convert them back, but it would be nice if it could map from one data type to another.

Comment: I guess it's not the case unfortunately... this would indeed need a `as.numeric` as final wrapper.

Comment: what if i am working on Chinese data ? , tolower( ) would not work for those.

Comment: well, this is the way to get the result you want since you have `John` and `john` in the data you gave... most of the other answer did not took that in consideration and corrected these differences on their side implicitely.

Comment: yes , that was a mistake while composing the question

Answer (score 1):

If we could remove factors:

```
df3 <- data.frame(lapply(df, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

then

```
df3[!is.na(df3)] <- match(df3[!is.na(df3)] , as.character(df1[,1]))
```

Comment: This caused `df` to fill with `NA` values for me.